# Stern and Gerlach experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics

> The state of a spin-$\frac12$ particle that is spin up along the axis whose direction is specified by the unit vector $n=\sin\theta\cos\phi i+\sin\theta\sin\phi j+\cos\theta k,$ is given by $$|+n \ \rangle=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|+z \ \rangle + e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|-z \ \rangle.$$
>
> a. Suppose that a measurement of $S_z$ is carried out on a particle in the state $|+n \ \rangle.$ What is the probably that the measurement yields $\hbar/2$, $-\hbar/2$. How about the measurements of $S_x?$
>
> b. Determine the uncertainty $\triangle S_z$ and $\triangle S_x$ of your measurements.

I know how to the measurement of $S_z$ for parts a and b, but I am not sure how to do the measurements for $S_x$. I have:

For reference, $$|+x \ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|+ z \ \rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt2}|-z \ \rangle$$ $$|+y \ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|+ z \ \rangle+\frac{i}{\sqrt2}|-z \ \rangle.$$

a.) Probability for $\hbar/2$: $$|\langle \ +z |+n \rangle|^2 = \cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$
Probability for $-\hbar/2$: $$|\langle \ -z |+n \rangle|^2 = \left|e^{i\phi}\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\right|^2=\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}.$$

But I am not sure how to do it for $S_x?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the probability of measuring $\left|+x\right\rangle$ you need to determine the expression $\left|\left\langle+x\middle|+n\right\rangle\right|^2$. You have the expression for $\left|+n\right\rangle$ and you have the expression for $\left|+x\right\rangle$. Therefore you first need to determine the bra vector $\left\langle +x\right|$ which is found by taking the complex conjugate of each coefficient in the $\left|+x\right\rangle$ expression and turning all of the ket vectors to bra vectors. Doing this, we find the following:

$$\left\langle+x\right|= {1 \over \sqrt{2}}\left\langle+z\right|+{1 \over \sqrt{2}}\left\langle-z\right|.$$

You can then use this expression along with the expression given for $\left|+n\right\rangle$ to find:

$$\left\langle+x\middle|+n\right\rangle=\left({1 \over \sqrt{2}}\left\langle+z\right|+{1 \over \sqrt{2}}\left\langle-z\right|\right)\left(\cos{\theta \over 2}\left|+z\right\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin{\theta \over 2}\left|-z\right\rangle\right)$$
$$\Longrightarrow{1 \over \sqrt2}\cos{\theta \over 2}+{e^{i\phi} \over \sqrt2}\sin{\theta \over 2}.$$

Then, you simply find the modulus squared of this expression to obtain the probability of measuring $+{\hbar \over 2}$. The process is entirely similar for finding the probability of measuring $-{\hbar \over 2}$, the only difference being that you use the bra $\left\langle-x\right|$ rather than $\left\langle +x\right|$.

Comment: I've improved your equations a bit. Please see my edits to learn how to typeset equations nicer in future. In general, one should prefer `\left` and `\right` to denote starting and ending brackets/braces/parens. Then the sizes will be automatically selected. `\big` is only for some special cases which are quite rare. And many functions have commands to make them look like functions, e.g. `\sin`. If there's no such command, you can use `\operatorname{func}`, e.g. `\operatorname{Ai}(x)` will give $\operatorname{Ai}(x)$.